# Playing through an entire game with baby pokemon

Tags: pokemon-series

In any of the Pokemon games, is it possible to do an entire playthrough with baby Pokemon? You know, like Elekid, Magby, etc... This is something I would like to attempt, but not sure if their stats are high enough to get through the game.

Comment: I'm not fully sure of Elekid / Magby, but do you mean playing through with a Poke'mon that you don't let evolve? Or one that simply doesn't evolve (like Zapados). If you are talking about not letting a Poke'mon evolve, it's definitely possible.

Comment: @leety I mean baby Pokemon hatched from eggs. I can keep them from evolving so that isn't an issue. I don't want to use a non-evolving Pokemon such as legendaries.

Comment: It is easy to give one a fish when hungry.  But if you teach a man to fish, he can eat for a life time.  Go... young pond skipper, go on your journey of discovery.  Try and attempt this on your own. There's a difference between learning and leaning.

Answer (score 5):

Sure it's possible. It would require plenty of grinding (for both levels and EVs) and liberal use of the Steroids (Calcium, Iron, etc), but you could do it.

Comment: Agreed. Baby Pokemon have low stats (e.g. Magby's base stat total is 365, compared to Magmar's 495), but there are baby Pokemon of numerous types and they tend to learn moves normally. It's way more feasible than the solo Caterpie run someone tried, but you'd need to really level grind to beat the Elite Four, and that'll take a lot of effort.